# Generate grouped std deviation columns with summarise() and t.test() results

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, summarize, t-test

I am performing many t-tests with similar grouping variables called `group` (0 or 1) to test the difference in means, for 2* `instruments`. The groups are defined differently according to `external`. To streamline output, I am using `dplyr()` to perform t-test multiple times and then `tidy` to clean up the t-test outputs.

QUESTION: How can I add 2 columns: sd1 with the standard deviation for estimate1 and sd2for std dv of estimate 2. That way I can report mean (SD) for each group in the t-test, for each external measure and for each instrument. So each row within the columns should have a unique SD

*in reality, many more

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

# Example dataframe
data <- structure(list(external = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex1",  "ex1", "ex3", "ex1", "ex1", "ex1",  "ex2", "ex3", "ex2", "ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex3", "ex2", "ex1", "ex3", "ex2", "ex1", "ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex1", "ex3", "ex1", "ex2", "ex2", "ex2", "ex1"
), group = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                       1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                       2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), instrument = c("in1", "in2", "in1", "in2", "in2",                                                                    "in2", "in1", "in1", "in2",                                                                    "in2", "in1", "in2", "in2",                                                                    "in2", "in2", "in1", "in1",                                                                    "in1", "in1", "in2", "in1",                                                                    "in2", "in1", "in1", "in1",                                                                   "in2", "in2", "in1", "in1", 
                                                                                                "in2"), changescore = c(0.044, 0.228, 0.39840119328, 0.055422675, 0.292, 0.388, 0.741, 0.037, 0.182, 0.0459999999999999, 0.05105604, 0, 0, 0, 0.646, 0.15, 0.0379999999999999, -0.102,   0.37, 0.396, 0.109, 0, 0.633, 0.247, 0.151, 0.0449999999999999,  0.172, 0, 0, 0.223473)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
  
 
# Perform t-tests on 2 groups for each external & instrument
data %>%
  group_by(external, instrument) %>%              
  summarise(tidy(t.test(changescore ~ group,     
                        var.equal = T  
                        )))



## PRODUCES:

# A tibble: 6 x 12
# Groups:   external [3]
  external instrument estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method        alternative
  <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      
1 ex1      in1          0.0132     0.234    0.221     0.0549 0.958           5   -0.605     0.631 Two Sample t… two.sided  
2 ex1      in2          0.302      0.336    0.0335    5.15   0.00676         4    0.139     0.465 Two Sample t… two.sided  
3 ex2      in1          0.0654     0.140    0.075     0.410  0.710           3   -0.442     0.573 Two Sample t… two.sided  
4 ex2      in2          0.140      0.228    0.0885    1.22   0.310           3   -0.224     0.503 Two Sample t… two.sided  
5 ex3      in1          0.608      0.633    0.0245    2.78   0.220           1   -2.18      3.39  Two Sample t… two.sided  
6 ex3      in2          0.328      0.328    0         0.942  0.446           2   -1.17      1.83  Two Sample t… two.sided
```

*Note: `estimate` = difference in means, `estimate1` = mean for group 1, `estimate2` = mean group 2.

QUESTION: How can I add 2 columns: `sd1` with the standard deviation for estimate1 and `sd2`for std dv of estimate 2. That way I can report mean (SD) for each group in the t-test, for each `external` measure and for each `instrument`. So each row within the columns should have a unique SD

I have tried adding snippets like `summarise (sd1   = sd( changescore, na.rm = T) )` within the `summarise()` function, but it either produces NAs down the whole column, or repeats the same value. Adding `mutate()` after did not produce as desired. Not sure where or what to add if the data are already grouped & summarized...

Thanks!

Comment: But you are using `var.equal =TRUE` meaning you are taking the assumption that the two samples have equal variance. Whats the purose of calculating the individual sd's then?

Comment: @Onyambu Standard reporting purposes. I may decide to change `var.equal` later, but will still need the SDs.